# Storing and searching similar phrases

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

Let's say I want to store an item in my database like "visit Spain". However, I'm going to allow user submissions, and I'd like to keep track of all the users who wish to visit Spain, however I'd like them to be able to type "Visit Spain" as well as "Go to Spain", "See Spain", or "tour spain".
I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Currently my thinking has me going along these lines (simplified):

- Nouns

  1. uniqueId

     noun

     verb [fk]

  Verbs

  1. uniqueId

     verb

  synonyms

  1. uniqueId

     verb [fk]

     synonym

Am I off base, or is this the best way to be going about it? I'm looking for both performance and ease of maintenance...

Comment: Build a `FULLTEXT` index on your column and then use MySQL's [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: well, i'm using InnoDB so I can take advantage of foreign keys, which means I can't use full text indexes...

Comment: Depends on the version of MySQL that you're using: full-text search is supported on InnoDB from v5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into some simple natural language processing (NLP).

Ideally, you need to normalize the input so that you can search for users that have the same normalized values.

1. First tokenize the input, separating the words.  "Visit Spain" would become ("Visit", "Spain") and "
2. Look for single words that have equivalences.  For example, you can ignore case for many things.
3. Use table lookup to find more advanced single word equivalences, such as "Visit" => "Tour", "See" => "Tour".  Using this ("Visit", "Spain") and ("See", "Spain") would both be translated to ("Tour", "Spain")
4. Look for phrase equivalences.  For example "go to" => "Visit".  This would make ("Go", "to", "Spain") become ("Tour", "Spain").
5. Apply pattern matching.  For example ("Tour" X "and" Y) => ("Tour" X), ("Tour" Y) could become two separate items, ("Tour", "Spain") and ("Tour", "France").
6. When you have applied all of your transformations, store the resulting normalized items.

Your work is in defining classes of translations, finding many instances of those translations, and then applying them to your input.

Once you have a normalized item, you can search for other users that have the same normalized item.

Comment: I don't think it appropriate to put this in the answer: I have a friend who took Coursera's NLP course https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp and really liked it.  It looks like their videos are still visible under the preview.